# Folder Structure vs Filter Parameters for Accessing Historical Documents

Tags: filter, structure, folders, document

Do we need folders or a paginated list with filter parameters (Time-range, file type, etc.) to easily access the historical data such as invoices in a cloud repository application?

With a folder structure, users can easily access a document set. But a default list with filter parameters can provide greater flexibility in narrowing down results with less organizational clutter and other hassles of folder management. Which would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think based on the circumstance where it is used, if the user's action (open, close & checking) is mostly towards a single type (example - docs.) of files then following the folder structure with the listing of documents as in recently added with a search option will be better,

Or, if the user will be using multiple types of files mostly with respect to time, then the list view (paginated list) will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who your users are. Since you didn't specify, I will use my own experience in developing archival software (documents/pictures) for my answer: The people who tend to use this software are not the most tech savvy. These were usually older people (sometimes volunteers during their retirement) who wanted a simple system.

I would try to make it similar to the Windows folder system. That way you're leveraging what Windows is already teaching to people for your own application. You can always add extra filters as an option for users who want to use them.